How to stop SwiftUI .relative Text field after it reaches zero?
I am working with SwiftUI's .relative and/or .timer text field, which keeps on counting upwards, once it hits zero.
Text(departureTime.time, style: .relative)

Yes, I know, there is a similar question here, but that does take a different approach, by only using one Date attribute, and forcing the timeline to update, once it hits zero. However, I have multiple Dates and an API limit, so I strictly need to hide/unhide Text() elements that are in the past.
Is there a way, to make the Text field disappear once it hits zero, or make it display a different text? This approach does not seem to work:
ForEach(departureInfo.departureTimes.prefix(3), id: \.self) { departureTime in
    let timeRemaining = departureTime.time.timeIntervalSince(Date())
    Text(timeRemaining > 0 ? "\(departureTime.time, style: .relative)" : "")
                                    
                                }


I assume this is also in a widget environment?

Yes, indeed, this is in WidgetKit

you will have to remove the element from the departureTimes array. timeRemaining is created in forEach and it doesn't cause view to redraw because its not a state variable. I guess you would need to reload the timeline according to the timer.
